# How do I fix bugged quests on consoles?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, ps3

I know that PC has console to fix their bugged quests, but is there a way to fix bugged quests on the 360 or for that matter, the PS3?

My bug is I got a companion quest from Falkas to intimidate someone in Markarth. I didn't do it right away, got sidetracked with other things in the game, and finally went and completed the quest. The quest now says "Return to Falkas" and adds a marker over him. He doesn't allow me to complete the quest, he says "aren't you running a job for Vilkas? Come to me when you finished that."

I'm going to assume that I'm SOL since the 360 doesn't have a console to run commands from.

**EDIT**

It seems as though I had another quest from Vilkas where I had to retrieve a Steel Dagger from Southfringe Sanctum. I completed that quest and was able to complete the quest for Falkas.

Comment: why not trying to do the quest for vilkas then continue with falkas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Xbox is a closed system. Your PC is an open system. The Xbox is centered around the experience and Microsoft / Bethesda control the content available to you. This is not the case with PCs. There is no console option for the Xbox.

One strategy to deal with bugs is to load a previous safe point.

Comment: to expand on your last sentence, one strategy is to create several save points as you play, always trying to preserve one that goes back before your current "quest". Skyrim's system makes it difficult to do that, but as an alternative, you can try to keep at least two save points prior to the completion of your last quest (in case the most recent save is not before the bug takes effect).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on ps3. Kill him. You get a little talking to from Falkas but you can continue anyhow. That's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox One and Xbox Series X/S players can use the [**Multi-Utility 6.1** by Selyb (XB1 port)](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4067343) mod to run console commands that can fix quests, among other console commands. For Xbox 360 players, the [original mod](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/) requires a JTAG-RGH modded console.

[image: Screenshot of Multi-Utility 6.1 menu]

> This is a port of Selyb Multi-Utility 6.1 for JTAG-RGH Xbox 360 Skyrim players. This mod is a "console command"–like menu, which gives all Xbox players almost all PC console commands. What once was an exclusive feature to PC Skyrim is now available for Xbox One users.

> Usage: Equip Multi-Utility from Powers in the Magic menu.

Make sure to read the [UESP wiki article on console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), the [description on the mod page](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4067343), and the [post about the original Xbox 360 mod](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206002222/https://www.xboxchaos.com/topic/2839-multi-utility-mod-by-selyb/) first, as the instructions for running some of the console commands may differ from the PC.

Here are the quest-related console commands that it supports:

> - Quests
>
>   - Toggle Active
>   - Complete Quest
>   - Start/Stop
>   - Reset
>   - SetStage
>   - CompleteAllObjectives
>   - FailAllObjectives
>   - Objective Menu
>
>     - Toggle Completed
>     - Toggle Failed
>     - Toggle Visible

---

Another alternative for Xbox One and Xbox Series X/S players is the [**Quest Debugger** (XB1)](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/3594817) mod.

> The Quest Debugger mod is an advanced utility used to fix quests, it can be used to skip them but I don't recommend it. It requires YOU, the user to do research.
>
> In short, it allows you to debug any quest in the game. Complete it, advance its stage, etc...
>
> A Spell and a book get added to the players inventory when installed and enabled.

Like for Multi-Utility, it is recommended that you read the [UESP wiki article on console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) first to familiarize yourself with console commands before using the mod.